# storing student data in python list to get percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
import re
import os
import sys
class Marks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.marks = []
        self.marks_file = '/root/projectpython/mark.txt'
    def loadAll(self):
        file = open(self.marks_file, 'r')
        for line in file.readlines():
            name,math,phy,chem = line.strip().split()
            name=name
            math=int(math)
            phy=int(phy)
            chem=int(chem)
            self.marks=[name,math,phy,chem]
            print(self.marks)
        file.close()

    def percent(self):
        dash = '-' * 40
        self.loadAll()
        for n in self.marks:
            print(n)

Book_1 = Marks()
Book_1.percent()
```

output:-

```
['gk', 50, 40, 30]
['rahul', 34, 54, 30]
['rohit', 87, 45, 9]
rohit
87
45
9
```

but i want to print all value in tabular format,it showing only last record.
is it correct method to use list to store student data name and marks.

Answer (score 1):

problem here is with the line read

```
self.marks=[name,math,phy,chem]
```

this will keep reinitializing the list each time mark is read

instead use:

```
self.marks.append([name,math,phy,chem])
```

Answer (score 0):

You continue to initialize the list in the `for` statement
and declare it so that only the array value of the last line is reflected.

I think you can remove the initialization statement and process it as an `append`.

```
import re
import os
import sys
class Marks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.marks = []
        self.marks_file = '/root/projectpython/mark.txt'
    def loadAll(self):
        file = open(self.marks_file, 'r')
        for line in file.readlines():
            name,math,phy,chem = line.strip().split()
            name=name
            math=int(math)
            phy=int(phy)
            chem=int(chem)
            self.marks.append(name)
            self.marks.append(math)
            self.marks.append(phy)
            self.marks.append(chem)
            # self.marks=[name,math,phy,chem]
            print(self.marks)
        file.close()

    def percent(self):
        dash = '-' * 40
        self.loadAll()
        for n in self.marks:
            print(n)

Book_1 = Marks()
Book_1.percent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `self.marks=[name,math,phy,chem]` as `self.marks.append([name,math,phy,chem])`.
Then easiest solution is to transpose the `self.marks` list and print them.

suppose your `marks` list is `[['gk', 50, 40, 30],['rahul', 34, 54, 30],['rohit', 87, 45, 9]]` then simply transpose it.

```
print(marks)

transposed=list(zip(*marks))
print(transposed)
for x in transposed:
    print(x)
```

output :

```
[['gk', 50, 40, 30], ['rahul', 34, 54, 30], ['rohit', 87, 45, 9]] #marks list

[('gk', 'rahul', 'rohit'), (50, 34, 87), (40, 54, 45), (30, 30, 9)] #transposed list


('gk', 'rahul', 'rohit')  # output the way you want
(50, 34, 87)
(40, 54, 45)
(30, 30, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working now.
i was doing mistake earlier here only self.marks.append([name,math,phy,chem])

[['gk', 50, 40, 30], ['rahul', 34, 54, 30], ['rohit', 87, 45, 9]]

Comment: check my solution I have added extension to your code so that the output looks like a table.